# What is the great wisdom in defining your own object if I can't do this?

Tags: excel, vba, return-value, user-defined-functions, return-type

This is for Excel and VBA. Assume that BondClass has been properly defined in a Class Module. I get a #VALUE! when I type "=GetBondPrincipal()" into an Excel cell. Have I done something syntactically wrong or is this just not possible in Excel/VBA? I ask because what I really want to do is this:
[Return a User Defined Data Type in an Excel Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354046/return-a-user-defined-data-type-in-an-excel-cell)

but am unable to find a solution. So at the very least, I want to know if what I want to do below is possible.

```
Option Explicit
```

Function InitializeBond(ir As Double, p As Double) As BondClass
   Dim mybond As BondClass
   Set mybond = New BondClass
   Call mybond.Initialize(ir, p)
   InitializeBond = mybond
End Function

Function GetBondPrincipal()
   Dim b As BondClass
   Set b = New BondClass
   b = InitializeBond(0.03, 100) //the code quits here, 
                                 //it doesn't like the BondClass return type?
   GetBondPrincipal = b.GetPrincipal()
End Function

I know that in the example I have provided, I don't have to call InitializeBond and can simply type "Call b.Initialize(.03,100)". The code will work fine if I do this. But I can't seem to be able to get a UDF to return a type other than the built-in types. Any way to do any of this? Do I have to define assignment for non-built-in types?

Comment: "Call myBond.Initialize(ir, p)" could/should just be "myBond.Initialize ir, p" in VBA

Comment: i don't like the latter notation. i prefer using Call. are there performance issues when one uses Call?

Comment: You're using VBA.  Stop pretending to worry about performance.  ;)

Comment: that's exactly why i care about performance. every hour counts. if this were c++ i wouldn't care about an inefficiency here or other, since things on a whole are fast. but VBA ... some things are terribly slow and some things are less slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use "SET".

(most common error made by VB programmers in VB6 and VBA).

Comment: thanks! that does it! it was a bit infuriating! :)
would you mind taking a look at this question and giving me your thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354046/return-a-user-defined-data-type-in-an-excel-cell

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I don't find that very elegant.
I would rather write:

```
Function GetBondPrincipal()
   Dim b As BondClass
   Set b = New BondClass
   with b
     .param1 = 0.03
     .param2 = 100
     .InitializeBond
     GetBondPrincipal = .GetPrincipal()
   end with
End Function
```

Comment: InitializeBond is not part of the BondClass class. i don't allow for parameters to be set individually. from what i understand there aren't default constructors, thus i require parameters to be set through the class .Initialize function, which the user of the class should call after each instantiation of the class.