# Values storable in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel, office-interop

Good evening!

Which types of values can be directly stored into an Excel worksheet using `Range.Value2` and how do I quickly check if a particular value can?

Suppose I have an array of objects, perhaps multityped (e.g. one `int`, one `double` and one `Foo` stored in an `object[]`).

If I shall choose a range of width 3 and try to store this array using `Range.Value2`, this will result in an exception (of course Excel doesn't know what is a `Foo`).

I came up with an idea of checking each value in the array, and, if it's not storable, convert it to its string representation using `ToString()`. But how do I check if it's initially storable?

It would be horrible to end up doing something like that:

```
public bool storable<T>(T value)
{
     return value is int  ||
            value is uint ||
            value is short ||
            value is byte ||
            ...
            value is string;
}
```

...especially knowing that each `is` will **cast** the variable to the tested type and seriously affect performance.

On the other hand, I can't afford pre-casting **each** value to the `string` type as I sometimes want to be able to do graphs and diagrams with numeric values, not strings.

Can you tell me I am mistaken or offer me any solution to the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't speak to doing this in C#, but just to get familiar with what Excel can store, look at the Excel SDK. They key concept is the XLOPER (or XLOPER12) `struct`, which contains a gnarly `union`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869.aspx . For a more casual answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354046/return-a-user-defined-data-type-in-an-excel-cell/1365314#1365314 . If you are developing some kind of add-in, see: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to do what you're unkeen to do (all the "is" checks), unless you can somehow make your input array a bit more strongly typed. Your best bet might be just to order the casts such that the most common ones get hit first.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I guess there's no other way to to it.