# Using SUMIFS with Criteria as a List in a Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to store the multiple criteria of a SUMIFS function in a single cell with each individual criteria separated by a comma.

I realize you can do this by having each criteria in a separate cell, but I need to have each criteria in a single cell separated by commas (or some other delimiter).

The closest I've gotten is seen in the screenshot below.  Cell E4 is the formula if I hard code the criteria (an account of 500 or 600).  However, if I put those criteria in the criteria cell, E2, and reference the E2's value/contents through the CELL function, it returns the value "500","600" as """500"",""600""" because it escapes the double quotes and then interprets the value as a text string rather than a list of texts.

Does anyone know how to make cell E2's value be a list of text/strings so that it can be passed into the SUMIFS criteria parameter?

[image]

Comment: You'd need to write a UDF to do the conversion.  See [Excel: pass array argument to formula through cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920251/excel-pass-array-argument-to-formula-through-cell-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I was hoping there was a way to do it without a UDF as I'd rather not have to write an add-in to make the function available to all users.  I've written a function which accomplishes this now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be `SUMIFS`?

If you format `E2` as text then input 500,600 you can use this formula for the sum

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&B2:B8&",",","&E2&","))+0,C2:C8)`

See screenshot

[image]